# Unity Facebook SDK is keeping on asking me to confirm login every time I login to my game

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3D 2018.2.6f1 With Facebook SDK.

This is the code I'm using to login into facebook once the user clicked on the login button:

```html
            FB.Init(()=>FB.LogInWithReadPermissions
            (
                new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email" },
                result_ =>
                {
                    //....
                }
            ));
```

I'm testing the login behavior on an android device.

The first time I log in it requires a username and a password which is great.
But each time afterward it will prompt me with a message that says:

"You previously logged in to myAppName with Facebook. Would you like to continue?"

And it lets me choose between "continue" and "cancel".

Is there a way to avoid this message?

In the game "Coin Master" for example, I don't see this message every time I log into the game after I already logged in once with facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook sdk has a IsLoggedIn method to determine if someone is already logged. You might want to call it before doing your loginwithreadpermission call.

Maybe something like this:

```
private void OnFacebookInitialized()
{
    if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
      // you are not logged, call loginWithReadPermission
    else
      // you are already logged in, do something
}
// ...
FB.Init(OnFacebookInitialized); // init FB
```

See documentation of [FB Session Properties](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/Properties/) for more information

Comment: Thanks, but Is it possible for a player to still be logged in after not opening the game for about two weeks? ( This is what happened in coin master for example, and it still didn't ask anything )

Comment: Yes, when you log to facebook, you get an accesstoken. This token is what is used by the sdk to verify if the user is logged. It has however by default a validity period that is around 60 days. As long as your user uses the app within that time period, he shouldn't have to log again. Also the isLoggedIn method will check automatically the presence and validity of tokens, you won't have to worry about that. You can have more information about accestokens here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens

Comment: This worked for me too, checking IsLoggedIn before calling LogInWithReadPermission worked perfectly.  No more annoying login popups!  They should really update the example code to run like this.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I face this problem also but FB.IsLoggedIn return false. Is this solution only for the logged in users, non-logged in users still get this problem?